# matlab imread or fread?

Tags: matlab, fread

i have a question :D

sorry for my bad english.

i have a grayscale 3D image, and i want to do some image processing with matlab, i can read this 3D image (1000*1000*1000) as .raw or as image sequences.

if i read it as .raw i will use fread and i will have 1D array.
if i read it as image sequences i will have a 3D array.

so what is the best solution to have a short time of execution?... we suppose that my program will just browse all the pixels ...

my real program will do labeling of 3D image... what is the best data structure under matlab to do that ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: if you read it as `1D`, just run: `img_3d = reshape(img_1d, [1000, 1000, 1000]);`. If needed, you can use `permute()` then.

Answer (score 0):

Read about DICOM. It's a standard for medical images like tomograms (3D images as well). Matlab has a function dicomread.
[link here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html)

Comment: Thanks to you.
with using a 1D array i can get quick access then 3D array ?

Comment: I don't understand your question:)

Comment: if i use 1D array to represente all the 3D image it will be better then using 3D array ?

Comment: 3D array is more useful for 3D images.